# Транзакции в Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, сессия, servlet

Имеется jsp-страница, в которой подключается фрагмент:

```
<jsp:include page="WEB-INF/templates/header.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

В этом фрагменте происходят запросы в БД, используется hibernate. Раньше в DAO-слое на каждое действие открывалась сессия, делалась транзакция. И все работало корректно. Теперь перевожу приложение на session-per-request. Сессия открывается и транзакция отслеживается в фильтре. В дескрипторе web.xml добавил HibernateSessionFilter:

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>HibernateSessionFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.filter.HibernateSessionFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>  
        <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>  
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
    </filter-mapping>
```

В фильтре устроено все так:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();

            filterChain.doFilter(request, response); 
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();

        } catch (StaleObjectStateException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
                try {
if(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().isActive()) {
      sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();
                    }
                } catch (Throwable ex) {

                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                throw new ServletException(e);
            }
        }
```

Внезапно стало бросаться исключение: `org.hibernate.HibernateException: createCriteria is not valid without active transaction`

Возникает оно на строчке создания критерии:

```
Criteria criteria = this.currentSession.createCriteria(Setting.class);
```

Хотелось бы понять причину такого поведения. Предполагаю, при включении фрагмента в jsp-страницу перед отдачей ее клиенту транзакция уже закрыта и из-за этого такая ошибка.

Comment: А как вы сессию получаете?

Comment: критерия создается здесь? "filterChain.doFilter(request, response); "

Comment: filterChain.doFilter(request, response); перенаправляет запрос на сервлет, который использует DAO-классы для работы с базой. Критерии создаются именно в DAO.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте, является ли одним и тем же объектом `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` в фильтре и `this.currentSession` в бизнес-логике. Это можно сделать либо под отладкой, либо вставив строчки трассировки (`System.out.println(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession())`). Если окажется, что это разные объекты, то либо надо получать текущую сессию другим способом, либо применить решение "в лоб" - из фильтра передавать `currentSession` в бизнес-логику, например, как параметр http-сессии...

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо перейти от `currentSession=factory.getCurrentSession()` к `factory.openSession()` - дело в том, что `currentSession` закрываются автоматически, что у вас очевидно и происходит. Сессии полученные через `openSession()` - требуют более ответственного подхода, надо вручную коммитить/флашить.

А так в общем то то же самое.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
Criteria criteria = session.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction().createCriteria(Setting.class);
```